# Shrinkwrapping on creases problem

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, shrinkwrap

I want to ask why my shrink wrap object can't wrap along the depression area?

Thank you guys!

Blender file provided below.

[image: Picture]

[image]

Comment: Give a try to the "project" (in mode) option, with "negative" and "above surface".

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: @lemon Hey Thank you it worked! But I have another problem. I got this glitch I can't seem to figure out how to remove it after playing around the other options.

Comment: https://ibb.co/9hHbjS6

Comment: @CalvinQ.Valencia, I don't think there is a general way to parameter this. What you can do is to help the shrinkwrap a bit modeling or sculpting closer to the target shape.